# Doxygen. Error: Could not open file .../doc/html/functions_.html for writing

Tags: doxygen

Строю документацию по *.java файлам, doxygen выдает ошибку "Error: Could not open file .../doc/html/functions_.html for writing" на шаге "Generating member index...".
Ошибка возникает не всегда, закономерность непонятна. Чаще всего - если есть классы количеством методов более 200, с длинными названиями методов и большим количеством параметром. Количество строк роли не играет. Для эксперимента я убрал код методов, оставил только объявления, около 300 (строк получилось тоже около 300). Если, например, половину методов убрать, то ошибка уходит.

Comment: В выражении "functions_?.htm" на месте знака вопроса идет символ ASCII 16 или 18. Т.к. этот символ непечатный, то вероятнее всего ошибка возникает из-за него. Вопрос в том, откуда он там берется? Исходники - в UTF-8.

Comment: Дружище, решил проблему? Поделись пожалуйста.

Comment: Решил. В репозитории доксигена на гитхабе лежит исправленая версия исходников. Компилируй и пользуйся.